# Route pattern in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Hi. Is this possible to separate URL parameters for two placeholder *{Name}* and *{Surname}* like below ?**

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Users",
                    url: "Authorization/{Name}.{Surname}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Authorization", action = "Verify" }
                        );
```

**And in my action method use following code :**

```
private bool Verify (string Name,string Surname)
{
[...]
}
```

**Or do I have to use one placeholder and parse my string to extract information :**

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Users",
                    url: "Authorization/{UserName}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Authorization", action = "Verify" }
                        );
```

**And in Action method use following code :**

```
private bool Verify(string UserName)
{
 string name = "UserNameTillDot";  
 string surname = "UserNameAfterDot";
 [...]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the first approach, or are you asking us before you've tried it?

Comment: Yes. I have tried  and result is 404 Error

Comment: Url should follow some principles, so what you should rather try is `url: "Authorization/{Name}/{Surname}"`

Comment: But what I would like to achieve is to enable URL in this format website/name.surname by first solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is totally fine.
The problem is that your action in controller is defined as private:

Instead of

```
private bool Verify (string Name, string Surname)
{
[...]
}
```

It should be

```
public ActionResult Verify (string Name,string Surname)
{
    [...]
}
```

Also if you want to allow null for Name or Surname you should make them optional:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Users",
                    url: "Authorization/{Name}-{Surname}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Authorization", action = "Verify", Name = UrlParameter.Optional, Surname = UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
```

You also should place this route before your default route.

**EDIT:
There is a issue with "." in the route you can replace it with "-"**

Comment: The problem is with '.' in URL string . ASP NET MVC threat it as path to file .

Comment: So replace the "." with "-" and it will solve the issue